# List of natural numbers = > returns booleans

Tags: list, integer, boolean

Write a function that receives a list of natural numbers as a parameter and returns a list of Booleans. If a number in the list is even, then we will add True to the final list; for odd numbers we add False.

My attempt:

```
def my_int_list(list):
    new_list= []
    for num in list:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            num = True
            new_list.append(num)
        elif num % 2 != 0:
            num = False
            new_list.append(num)



my_list=[2,5,8]

print(my_int_list(my_list))
```

Comment: print(list(map(lambda x: not x % 2, my_list)))

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't call a variable `list` as it is a python built-in function, also you forgot to write return.

```py
def my_int_list(listt):
    new_list= []
    for num in listt:
        if num % 2:              # If there is 1 in reminder (more Pythonic)
            num = False
            new_list.append(num)
        else:                    # No need to Check reminder is 0?, because if reminder not 1 it always 0 (when divider is 2)
            num = True
            new_list.append(num)
    return new_list

my_list=[2,5,8]

print(my_int_list(my_list))
```

here in condition
`if num % 2:`
return true, only when a reminder is any number other than 0,
In our case, there is only two option 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution I can think of is by using `map`. `map(fun, iter)` is a function that returns a map object (an iterator) of the results after applying the given function to each item of it.

For example, using:

```
def my_int_list(lst):
    return list(map(even, lst))

def even(n):
    return n % 2 == 0
```

Allows you to return your int list as a boolean one:

`print(my_int_list([1,2,3,4,5,6])) # -> [False, True, False, True, False, True]`

Comment: omg looks so simple: D. I'm starting to like python more and more. The downside is that I haven't studied maps and many other things that definitely make the code shorter.
Thank you very much, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, this will do also

```
def my_int_list(my_list):
    new_list = []
    for num in my_list:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            new_list.append(True)
        elif num % 2 != 0:
            new_list.append(False)
    print(new_list)

my_list = [2, 5, 8]

my_int_list(my_list)
```

Comment: thank you very much! this is a more efficient option than what is above right?

Comment: Welcome! I just remove the `num` variable to be assigned as True or False. It's more efficient if `my_list` is very long. (=

Comment: But more important than being more efficient, it is simpler and easier to read

Comment: Great point @AxelB